# Conditional condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
 select * from table1 where id >20 and marks1 <40 and marks2 <30;
```

But i need to remove the last condition based on another condition for example

if `marks3 >40 then use marks2 <30` otherwise remove this condition.

Is it possible.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
select * 
from   table1 
where  id > 20 and 
       marks1 < 40 and 
       (
           (marks3 >40 and marks2 <30) or 
           mark3 <= 40
       )
```

Comment: `+1` for adding this: `(
           (marks3 >40 and marks2 <30) or 
           mark3 <= 40
       )`

Comment: @JW. Here i dont want to add marks3 > 40 condition .Just for checking the condition only i need this

Comment: @spiritwalker Here i dont want to add marks3 > 40 condition .Just for checking the condition only i need this

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. You just need to add your condition with an 'or' clause.

```
select * from table1 where id >20 and marks1 < 40 and (marks3 <= 40 or (marks3 > 40 and marks2 <30));
```

If **marks3 <= 40**, then the expression within outer parenthesis is evaluated to be **True**. It does not matter what the other condition is.
If **marks3 > 40**, then **marks2** has to be **< 30** for the expression within inner parenthesis to be evaluated as **True**, this making the complete outer parenthesis to be evaluated as **True**.

Comment: @PSR check the explanation as well :)

Comment: here i dont want to add marks3 > 40 condition .Just for checking the condition only i need this